# How to resolve ssl issue in ionic3 filetransfer?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm facing an issue while trying to use the IONIC Cordova File Transfer plugin to upload a file while the laravel Server is running in HTTPS.

I'm able to login to the application and access all APIs from the server with get and post, but when I try to use fileTransfer for uploading data I'm getting the below message.

```
body: null
code: 3
exception: "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."
http_status: null
source: "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16679"
target: "https://reddyflix.com/api/profile/photo/update"
```

I have dowloaded the (.cer) certificate file into the www directory of the project and setSSLCertMode = pinned. But I am still facing this issue.

```
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
httpMethod: "post",
chunkedMode: false,
fileKey: 'file',
fileName: 'name.png',
headers: headers
};
let trustAllHosts = true;        
fileTransfer.upload( 
uri,encodeURI('https://domain/api/profile/photo/update'), options,trustAllHosts)
.then((data) => {
console.log(data);
}, (err) => {
console.log(err);
})
```